# VBA programming in Excel withOUT ActiveCell

Tags: vba, loops, excel, countif

Does anyone know if it is possible to loop through an Excel spreadsheet using VBA without using ActiveCell?

As an example, how can you create the COUNTIF function from scratch in VBA without using ActiveCell (or calling on the COUNTIF function, obviously)?

I want to avoid ActiveCell because it seems like an unnecessary use of resources to scroll the active cell around when typically you're trying to manipulate a simple matrix, especially when looping through thousands of cells.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim c as Range

For Each c in Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1000").Cells
    'do something with c
Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

What Tim said.

Just to address the count-if portion of your question, here is a way to do it without using the formula:

```
Sub Macro14()

Dim c As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim count_if As Integer

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1000")

For Each c In rng
    If c = "Apple" Then
        count_if = count_if + 1
    End If
Next c

Debug.Print count_if
End Sub
```